# Python and FeedParser question

Tags: python, feedparser

I'm new to Python. I have this code using Feedparser:

```
import feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/')

i = range(10)

for i in range(10):
    updates = [{"url": d.entries[i].link, "msg": d.entries[i].summary + ", "}]
```

My question.

How can I add to the variable "updates" the 10 entries?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import feedparser

d = feedparser.parse('http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/')    
updates = []
for i in range(10):
    updates.append({"url": d.entries[i].link, "msg": d.entries[i].summary + ", "})
```

In your for loop, you append the dictionnary result to the updates list. 'updates' contains 10 elements after the for loop. One for each entry.

EDIT:

However, the code provided by RestRisiko is really more beautiful ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
d = feedparser.parse('http://pplware.sapo.pt/feed/')
for item in d.entries[:10]:
    print item
```

Extracting information from 'item' and adding it to a list or dict is basic usage of 
Python lists and dicts (please read the tutorial in this case - we must not teach very basic usage of lists and dicts here).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It need to store the values in a variable.